# Android Studio - checkout a *branch* from GitHub

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, intellij-idea

We have a repo in GitHub which has 3 branches. For example, say **master**, **developer** and **preview**.

When I checkout this repo in Android Studio, it seems to checkout the **master** branch only, ignoring all other branches. (Eclipse used to ask us which branch to checkout/import when we are cloning a repo from GitHub)

**The question is** : How can we select a branch at the time of checking out a repo into Android Studio?

*Image 1-* Checking out from GitHub

[image: Checking out from GitHub]

*Image 2-* It just asks for the repo URL, but **NOT** a branch.

[image: It just asks for the repo URL, but **NOT** a branch.]

Comment: Honestly, i'd learn how to use git. I know on window's it is a bit of pain to get it installed but you're better off learning how to use that tool than worrying about Android Studio.

Comment: Have you submitted a bug or change request to the android studio team? http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html

Comment: @cbrulak Thanks for the link, I am submitting a CR to the Studio team.

Comment: So how to check out a perticular branch .. is the issue solved. please help @VishnuHaridas

Comment: @Adi It seems that we need to checkout every branch, and switch to the one that we really need. Other than that, no good ideas yet.

Comment: @VishnuHaridas Thanks for the above comment. There is another issue. Today I created a branch say b in github repo in browser. but it is not reflected in my git branches in my android studio. How to refresh the repo here.

Comment: @Adi I think a "pull" command can retrieve all the branches from the repo. Or, it will update the local with new remote branches. Please check. (I continue development with Eclipse+Egit ! )

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In VCS menu, you choose git and click branch to choose which branch you want to use.

[image]

Or click right bottom corner git menu.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In AndroidStudio you have also the terminal (Tools --> Open Terminal, or View --> Tool Windows --> Terminal), open it, the current directory will be directly your project's, then just execute

```
git checkout the_name_of_the_branch
```

and that's all.
I would recommend you then to use this: http://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/add-git-branch-name-to-terminal-prompt-mac/ it will be much easier to see on which branch you are, directly in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The branch selection is done by two steps:

```
VCS-GIT-FETCH (unfetched externally created branch is invisible for you)
VCS-GIT-Branches-(Remote branches - branch name)-Checkout
```

The VCS-GIT-Branches can be reached by one click - in the right lower corner on GIT:[current branch name]