# Check out a branch from Git

Tags: git, branch, android-studio, bitbucket

I'm a bit new to Android Studio and I am trying to set up a project I recently checked out from Git. However, I don't want to check out everything, I just want to check out the branch because that branch has the module for my android project.The other branches don't have what is necessary to run the project. This question here: [Android Studio - checkout a *branch* from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17589828/1871869) is basically the same as mine. If anyone could help me, that would be great!

Comment: FYI: it is not good form to simply 'repost' an existing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that GIT fetches the whole repository, afterward you will be able to switch branch at will locally by using "git checkout " to consult a branch or "git checkout -b  " to start a development branch for yourself.

If you only want to get a single branch, maybe the repo has a browser which would allow you to get a .zip or .tar of the branch itself without having to use GIT.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. Would we simply have to use Git Bash (I use Windows) to switch to that branch then and access the repository there?

Comment: @user1871869: Yes, or use one of the available GUI options (unless the code you're interested in resides on the master branch).

Comment: On Windows I used [GIT Extension](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) which is a GUI to GIT and also installs Msys+Git for you.